# How to set rule in qradar if something does not occur in event payload for some time?

Tags: qradar

I would like to set rule, if qradar does not find the string in event payload for one week? How can I do it?

I am looking to list of conditions, but I did not find any suitable condition. I have this:
`when the event(s) have not been detected by one or more of there log source types for this many seconds`
However I think it is not very suitable for me, because I need to work with payload. Could someone help me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

One approach to resolve this problem is to use reference sets. A concept for this is explained [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/qradar-common?topic=spot-device-stopped-sending-events). You need two rules and a reference set:

###### Reference Set

Create a reference set and configure the time to live to the duration when the absence should be detected.

###### Rule 1 (Tracker Rule)

Set up a rule that triggers on the pattern whose absence you want to detect. In your case a string in the payload. Select "Add to a Reference Set" as rule response. Use the reference set from above.

###### Rule 2 (Watcher Rule)

Create a second rule which triggers on Event Name (or QID) "Reference Data Expiry". Maybe you need a custom event property for the name of the reference set and/or the expired element too. With this CEP you can test for the expiry of the item added from rule 1.